# Do food courts with multiple restaurants share food? e.g. is there a common shipping and storage area?

Tags: restaurant

I've never walked behind the food court in the mall. But just wondering if, behind the restaurants fascia, the individual restaurants are receiving incoming food shipments together. e.g. is there a common freezer and storage area? Or does each individual restaurant do their own thing? e.g. order and separate and receive their food independently.

Answer (score 3):

Can you imagine McDonald's sharing space with Burger King, or KFC?

I wouldn't even be sure they'd be allowed to even if they wanted. Each establishment would need its own compliance & hygiene certificate, which would be confounded if they shared space. Whose responsibility is each shared fridge in such circumstances? Who handles correct stock rotation? What happens if a KFC employee accidentally takes a bag of McDonald's fries?

Comment: That's definitely not allowed, not only from a food hygiene perspective or from financial / accounting perspective. In some countries you have restaurants that are indeed owned by the same legal entity and part of the same group of franchises, then the facilities and even personnel are shared (e.g. in Brazil there is a holding that owns a fried chicken franchise and a baked potato franchise, so they just split the restaurant in two at the front, part of the kitchen is shared and also stock, administrative personnel, etc.)

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza is much closer to what I've observed in the UK than this answer is. Look over the counter at a food court and through the door into the kitchen, and you may well see the uniforms of the next-door franchise.  The hygiene certificate and employment apply to the franchisee, which holds multiple franchises

Comment: Exactly, while the original answer is indeed correct, it doesn't consider that instance of multiple franchises owned by the same legal entity. If the legal entities are different - as in the example of McDonald's, Burger King and KFC - the original answer applies.

Comment: e.g. Does each one of these 3 restaurants http://tinyurl.com/y2vg6s33 maintain their own independent everything? e.g. their own storage, freezer, etc. I'm assuming they have a common loading bay--for trucks to drop off boxes. But is that where it ends?

Comment: @tdog2 Yes. Each one should have its separate storage, freezer, etc.

Comment: There are locations where two brands of the same parent company, like KFC and Taco Bell share a restaurant. I don't think I've ever seen it in a mall food court, but I don't spend much time in malls.